# R: fast way to take the mean of values of indices with given congruence?

Tags: r, performance, indexing

I have an array `X`, a number `n`, and would like to generate a vector `Y` of length `n` with `Y[i]` being the mean of all the `X[j]` with `j %% n == i` (all `j` congruent to `i` mod `n`).

For now, my code is something like this :

```
Y = vector("numeric",n)
Z = vector("logical",n)
for(i in 1:n) {
  Z[] = FALSE
  Z[i] = TRUE
  Y[i] = mean(X[Z])
}
```

This works, but as this operation has to run a fairly big number of times in my project, I wondered if there was a way to use built-in R functions or syntax in order to avoid the `for` loop.

Any help to make it faster without going to C would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example of `X`.

Comment: in the range 1 to n there is only one number `j` for which  `j` congruent to `i` mod `n`- This number is `j=i` So `Y[i]<-mean(X[i])`

Comment: 'j' is not in the range 1 to n, 'j' indexes X which has greater length than 'n'.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sapply` for this and based on the rule it will select the congruent numbers only:

```
n <- 10
X <- sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE)
Y <- sapply(1:n, function(i) mean(X[X %% n == i]))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the OP, but `sapply(split(X, X %% 10), mean)` seems like something similar.

Comment: This gives the mean of the values of X that are congruent to `i` mod `n`, but what I'm looking for is the mean of "one out of n" values of X (more precisely, the values whose index is congruent to `i` mod `n`). The code I posted does work, I'm just looking for a way to speed it up.